# Have I discovered a new significance to a previously discovered constant?

Tags: fibonacci-numbers, constants, infinitesimals

I've been interested in infinite sums for a while, though I have no formal education of them. I was messing around with repeated division and addition (e.g. 1 + (1 / (1 + (1 /...)))) I then plugged fibonacci numbers into the above pattern, and as I calculated more and more layers, the result converged to around 1.39418655, which I just now found out was a constant called Madachy's constant.  However, from the research that I did on the constant (I found very little), it doesn't seem to be related to infinite series or Fibonacci numbers at all. Have I found a new way to calculate this number? Does it give it any more significance? [image: The doodles that I did to find this]

Comment: Did you see this? https://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/6-6/madachy.pdf

Comment: Wow, that sounds like an answer to me ...

Comment: Also found in the OEIS as [A130701](http://oeis.org/A130701) which also has a link to the above paper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you see this? [fq.math.ca/Scanned/6-6/madachy.pdf](https://fq.math.ca/Scanned/6-6/madachy.pdf) It looks like it is exactly your calculation.

Friendly edit: This is in Fibonacci Quarterly, Volume 6 No. 6 page 385, as seen at [the cover of that issue](https://fq.math.ca/Scanned/6-6/cover6-6.pdf).

Comment: It seems I did not, I could only find stuff about magic squares. Thank you!

Comment: By the way @Cheerful_Parsnip - can you add a more proper reference for this?  Presumably it appeared in some publication, and that would add a lot of value to this answer - surely it will come up again!

Comment: @Kcrisman, if it were ever published, it's not indexed by MathSciNet. I found it by googling "Madachy constant."

Comment: "Readers of this Journal will note immediately that the terms of this continued fraction are successive Fibonacci terms."  That implies publication - got it: Unsurprisingly, Fibonacci Quarterly (which might not be indexed by MR, true) https://www.scribd.com/document/270530286/6-6 - oh, duh!  the domain name IS the Fibonacci Quarterly - fq.math.ca!  Actually it is indexed by MSN https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/journal_doc.html?groupId=1807

Comment: Hope the friendly edit is okay

Comment: @kcrisman Thanks. The article itself appears not to have been indexed by MSN even if the journal is.

Answer (score 0):

(*Too long for a comment*.) The OP's continued fraction which uses the *Fibonacci numbers* $F_n$ is

$$\mu =1+\cfrac{1}{2 + \cfrac{3} {5 + \cfrac{8} {13 + \cfrac{21} {34+\ddots}}}}=1.3941865\dots $$

which, as pointed out by Cheerful Parsnip, was previously investigated by Joseph Madachy and whose constant is designed by OEIS [A130701](http://oeis.org/A130701) as $\mu$.

However, there is continued fraction whose terms are also Fibonacci numbers and has a known closed-form,

$$\frac{F_{n+2}}{F_{n+1}} =1^2+\cfrac{(1\cdot1)^2} {1^2+ \cfrac{(1\cdot2)^2} {2^2 + \cfrac{(2\cdot3)^2} {3^2 + \cfrac{(3\cdot5)^2} {5^2 + \cfrac{(5\cdot8)^2} {F_n^2 + \cfrac{(F_{n}\cdot F_{n+1})^2}  {F_{n+1}^2+\ddots} }}}}}$$

If we truncate it at the $n$th term, we get that ratio. Note $\lim \frac{F_{n+1}}{F_{n}} = \phi$ as $n\to\infty$.

**P.S.** It would be nice if $\mu$ has a closed-form in terms of the golden ratio $\phi$ as well.

Comment: It won't let me make a one-character edit, but note the trivial potential edit that your spell checker put an "l" in Madachy's name.

Comment: @kcrisman: Thanks. Has been fixed.

Answer (score -2):

The [continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Other_continued_fraction_expansions) you are calculating will converge to the [golden ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio). It is most certainly a significant constant having history spanning several millennia.

Comment: The "all $1$s" continued fraction does indeed converge to the Golden Ratio. However, OP is interested in the continued fraction whose terms are the Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: But the golden ratio converges on the first continued fraction I mentioned, with only ones. With Fibonacci numbers, the fraction converges to a number ~.3 less than the golden ratio. The work I linked shows converging that starts with boundaries 1 and 1.5, so it couldn't end up converging to 1.618. Edit: just saw the reply above as I was typing this